# find a file within a tar.gz archive

Tags: find, tar

Is it possible to use the `find` command so that it searches the files within a tar.gz archive also using wildcards?

like

```
find archive.tar.gz --name *foo*
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about just:

```
$ tar tf archive.tar.gz | grep foo
```

Comment: doesnt that just list all the files?

Comment: @clamp Yes, if you want to do something to each file, simply pipe that output to another command.

Comment: thanks! sorry but im a newbie in unix. i tried: `tar tf graphics.tar.gz | find . --name *space*` but it says `unkown predicate --name`

Comment: @clamp `find` arguments only take one dash, but because it's a list of files on stdin, you want to use `grep` instead, like hesse's example code. Try `tar tf graphics.tar.gz | grep 'space'`

Comment: `grep *foo*` isn't a valid regular expression. `greg` doesn't understand globs, it understands regular expressions. Try `grep foo` instead.

Comment: @hesse: The egrep argument `*foo*` will be expanded by the shell to all filenames that contain foo. This may not be what OP really wants, perhaps you should say `"*foo*"`

Comment: @Gowtham Oh really?

Answer (score 3):

Mount the archive as a directory. You can do it with the [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem, which allows you to access any archive as a directory whose name has a trailing `#`.

```
mountavfs
cd ~/.avfs$PWD
find archive.tar.gz\# -name '*foo*'
```

Comment: not work for gzip

Comment: @vanabel A gzip file doesn't contain other files. It's just one file, compressed. So there's no “inside” to search in.

Answer (score 2):

I think it works with no pipe and grep.

like this:
`tar tvf archive.tar.gz "foo"`

> as this way, globs will also work.

`tar tvf archive.tar.gz "*.foo"`